# Exception and The Stack Trace

Tags: java, exception

What happens when we say `e.printStackTrace();`? Here `e` is any `Exception`. Does it stop the normal execution and actually remove the activation records from the thread stack to give the stack trace of the exception? Is it a good idea to use it in applications?

Comment: The stack trace is the thread stack when the exception was created, not where it was printed/logged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does it stop the normal execution

No.

> and actually remove the activation records from the thread stack to give the stack trace of the exception?

No.

The information has *already* been captured.  This happens in the constructors for `Throwable` ; i.e. when you `new` an exception, not when you `throw` it.  The `Throwable` constructor calls the `fillInStackTrace()` native method which takes a snapshot of the stack and stores the resulting `StackTraceElement[]` in a private variable that is used later when printing the stack trace.

(For the record, this is specified in the javadoc for the constructors of [`Throwable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html).

> Is it a good idea to use it in applications?

Well it is rather expensive and can produce a lot of output.  But if you *need* the stack trace for diagnostic purposes ... do it.

Comment: +1 However, fillInStackTrace doesn't populate the private array in the Sun JVM/JRE -- it is a native method which does the same (on the native side). getStackTrace pulls the native data back out and stores it into the private array as well.

Comment: @pst - most people would consider that `fillInStackTrace()` is (in the broad sense) doing the work.  Besides, the private native method call is a platform specific implementation detail.

Answer (score 4):

It just prints stack trace that is already held by exception object to STDERR. No side effects.

Comment: A small side effect is that the stack trace is not populated until it is used for performance reasons, usually the stack trace is not used. Its stored some where else, but you cannot see it in a debugger until its used in code.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey Elsewhere as in "somewhere native", but the "somewhere native" is normally filled in with `fillInStackTrace` which already has the "cost" of recording the stack. It's just the "cost" of pulling it from that native place into StackTraceElement objects that is bypassed.

Answer (score 3):

`e.printStackTrace();`

`e` is instance of [`Throwable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html)

and [`printStackTrace()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace%28%29)

> This method prints a stack trace for this Throwable object on the error output stream that is the value of the field System.err

Comment: standard error, not standard output. Although it does not matter in most cases

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing particularly clever going on. The `Exception` object contains a list of [StackTraceElements](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html), and it simply dumps them to stderr when the above is called.

Comment: It's a bit more clever than that ;-) The private array is used for serialization *and* caching (it's lazy-loaded and "nulled out" on fillInStackTrace). This is on (sun) JVM/JRE and is likely to store the stack-frame(s) more efficiently and expose them via a native method (I would guess in a more efficient non-object form). See http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Throwable.java

Answer (score 0):

As already said, there's no side effects and you won't introduce any issues per-se with using it in production code. I wouldn't really advise it (in production code) however, simply because in most applications it's much better to use a logger to get finer control of exactly what's logged and where it's logged to.

Answer (score 0):

The stack-trace is loaded via [`fillInStackTrace`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#fillInStackTrace%28%29) which is a native method that is called in the constructor of Throwable. (Neat tip: this method can be overloaded as a NOP for "signal exceptions" which do not need the rather expensive call to get the stack).

**The "freeze" of the stack trace *already exists for* the Throwable object when it is "caught".**

As per the code for [java.lang.Throwable](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Throwable.java) shows that `fillInStackTrace` is called as the first action of the constructor. The array of `StackTraceElement` is for serialization support (this can also be set manually) and as a lazy cache.

Even though that `fillInStackTrace` captures the trace it is *not* loaded into Java objects -- I suppose this allows the implementation to keep it "cheap" -- until it needs to be accessed as a sequence of `StackTraceElement` objects (e.g. for `printStackTrace` which is done in Java code). The code for Throwable shows this better than I can explain :-)

Happy coding.